# No getters and setters are called in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I am using `JPA 2.1` and while persisting and retrieving the `entities` from `database` I could see no `constructor` of the entity is called and not `getters` and `setters`. How does the `serialization` and `deserialization` take place then from `DB` object to `JAVA` object, if `getters`, `setters` and `constructor` are not called

**Teacher**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @Column
    String name;



    public Teacher(String name) {
        super();

        this.name = name;
    }

    public Teacher()
    {
        System.out.println("const");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("get Name");
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("set Name");
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**Main**

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
        EntityManager em1 = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        em1.getTransaction().begin();

        Teacher t = new Teacher("wick");

        em1.persist(t);

        Teacher t1= em1.find(Teacher.class, 21);


        em1.getTransaction().commit();
        em1.close();
```

Comment: can you share your codebase?

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate and similar libraries and frameworks often don't use (and require) getters and setters for accessing the properties of an objects. Java has several methods for inspecting and manipulating objects directly. This is called reflection. The entry point for this are often the method of the class [`Class`](http://localhost/books/Java/API-docs/JavaSE8/api/java/lang/Class.html) from the Java Standard API. Each class in Java has an associated instance of these class which provides several methods for getting information about the class. For example the method `getDeclaredFields` returns and array with data about all fields in the class. If you look into the documentation of the [`Field`](http://localhost/books/Java/API-docs/JavaSE8/api/index.html?java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class you see that there are several set methods which take an object (the instance of the object on which the value is set) and a value as parameters. This methods can also be used to bypass the access modifiers like `private` etc.

Best

Jens